# How can I combine two lists of lm models element-wise?

Tags: r, lm

I have two lists of fits generated by lm and I would like to combine them element-wise.

Right now, I have something like: fits1 = list(fit1, fit2, fit3) (where fit1, fit2, and fit3 are models generated by lm) and fits2 = list(fit4, fit5, fit6).

What I would like to do is produce a list combined elementwise: list(list(fit1, fit4), list(fit2, fit5),
list(fit3, fit6)).

I found some stuff about how to combine lists element-wise but all the solutions I've seen have required switching to a dataframe and you cannot include elements of class lm in a dataframe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Map` will give you what you are looking for.

```r
fits1 <- list("fit1", "fit2", "fit3")
fits2 <- list("fit4", "fit5", "fit6")

Map(list, fits1, fits2)
```

**Result:**

```r
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "fit1"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "fit4"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "fit2"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "fit5"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "fit3"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "fit6"
```

In `tidyverse` speak, that would use `purrr`.

```r
library(purrr)

map2(fits1, fits2, list)
```

Comment: This works perfectly!! Thank you so much, I didn't know this function existed.

Answer (score 2):

Another `base` solution

```
asplit(rbind(list1, list2), MARGIN = 2)
```

It's equivalent to

```
asplit(cbind(list1, list2), MARGIN = 1)
```

**Test**

```
fits1 <- list("fit1", "fit2", "fit3")
fits2 <- list("fit4", "fit5", "fit6")
asplit(rbind(fits1, fits2), 2)

[[1]]
[[1]]$fits1
[1] "fit1"

[[1]]$fits2
[1] "fit4"


[[2]]
[[2]]$fits1
[1] "fit2"

[[2]]$fits2
[1] "fit5"


[[3]]
[[3]]$fits1
[1] "fit3"

[[3]]$fits2
[1] "fit6"
```